# Rails 3 render action from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I need to render another controller action `<%= render "controller/index" %>`
and i get this error

> Missing partial controller/index with {:formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :erb, :builder]} in view paths "/path_to/app/views"

how can i render another controller action into a view but without sending an redirect to the client ?
I've tried

```
<%=render :action => "index", :controller=>"controller" %>
```

but it seems that is not working.

Comment: do you have an `index.html.erb` in `views/your_controller/`?

Comment: Why not use a redirect to the correct controller action?

Comment: Because the logic of the action may be totally different, and the only common thing between these actions is the view.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try to render template:

```
<%= render :template => "controller/index" %>
```

Or file:

```
<%= render :template => "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/controller/index" %>
```

And I believe you should render it through controller, as far as it is more convenient:

```
def your_action
  ...
  render :action => :index
end
```

Comment: I've try to use render :template but is rendering the html and i need to render the index method because the index method gets some data from DB needed for that view.

Comment: fl00r is right, best to handle this from within the controller. Note that there's a built-in fallback, if it can't find controller/index it renders application/index. So if there are pages (not partials) which have to be rendered from different controllers, put them under app/views/application.

Answer (score 21):

This works well for me :

```
def renderActionInOtherController(controller,action,params)
  controller.class_eval{
    def params=(params); @params = params end
    def params; @params end
  }
  c = controller.new
  c.request = @_request
  c.response = @_response
  c.params = params
  c.send(action)
  c.response.body
end
```

then, call by

```
render :text => renderActionInOtherController(OtherController,:otherAction,params)
```

basically it hacks the other class and overwrites its "params" method and return

If you are using Rails 4:

```
def renderActionInOtherController(controller,action,params)
    c = controller.new
    c.params = params
    c.dispatch(action, request)
    c.response.body
end
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, but I needed to add `c.process_action(action)` to get my `before_actions` to fire.

Comment: Damn, that's a neat hack. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20):

From Rails Guides [page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render):

> Using render with :action is a
>   frequent source of confusion for Rails
>   newcomers. The specified action is
>   used to determine which view to
>   render, but Rails does not run any of
>   the code for that action in the
>   controller. Any instance variables
>   that you require in the view must be
>   set up in the current action before
>   calling render.

So in short you can't render another action, you can only render another template.  You could get the shared code and move it to a method in application controller.  You could also try something along this lines if you really can't structure your code in some other way:

```
# This is a hack, I'm not even sure that it will work and it will probably
# mess up your filters (like ignore them).
other_controller = OtherController.new
other_controller.request = @_request
other_controller.some_action
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want just to render the `view` of the other controller (/model), but calling the `action` (method), think more the ruby way of life - put this method(s) into a `module` and include it in the controllers you need it.

I think its less 'spooky' then somehow touching an other controller.

```
module StandardActions
    def show_user_homepage(local_params=params)
        #something finding 
        #something to check
        render :"homepage/show" 
    def
end

class AddressesController < ApplicationController
    include StandardActions

    def update
        # update address
        if ok
            show_user_homepage(id: user_id)
        else
            #errorthings
            render :edit #(eg.)
        end
    end         
end

class HobbiesController  < ApplicationController
    include StandardActions

    def update      
        # update hobby
        if ok
            show_user_homepage(id: user_id)
        else
            #errorthings
            render :edit #(eg.)
        end
    end         
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rendering partials of another controller is no problem.
So why not moving the original action view to a partial and render this partial wherever you need it:

move app/views/controller_a/index.html.erb to
app/views/controller_a/_index.html.erb .

app/views/controller_a/index.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: 'index' %>
```

app/view/controller_b/some_action.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: 'controller_a/index' %>
```