# Rails: render template looking for the wrong partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I have a TasksController, and a SubtasksController. In a given moment of an action from SubtasksController I want to:

```
# app/controllers/tasks_controllers.rb
render 'tasks/index' # Or: render template: 'tasks/index'
```

When that action is called from the view though, it appears rails is trying to render the wrong partial:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial subtasks/tasks, private_area/tasks, application/tasks with {:locale=>[:ca, :es], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :slim, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/****/app/views"
```

I really don't understand what's going on here, any thoughts?

Comment: try `render '/tasks/index'`, does it help?

Comment: I tried that already :(, same results. @Bjoernsen

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051776/rails-3-render-action-from-another-controller question

Comment: Where is your partial located?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you render another controllers action the page that is displayed will look in the calling controllers views for any partials within itself.

You can get around this by explicitly declaring the path to partials within the page so that even when called from another controller it will always look in the right place.

```
# tasks/index page 
<%= render 'tasks/some_partial' %>
```

Now no matter which controller renders this page it will always look in `tasks` for its partials.