# Rails: render partial with selected controller and action in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, renderpartial

I have a Rails app where on the `home` page `home/index.html.erb`, I show a partial for the model `workorders`.  It currently defaults to the `home_controleer.rb` with the action `index`.

Can I select the `workorders_controller.rb` and action `index2`?

I tried this in the `home/index.html.erb` view file:

```erb
<%= render :partial => "workorders/index7", :controller => "workorders", :action => "index2" %>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

`<%= render :template => "workorders/index2" %>`

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051812/2128691

**edit**: in response to your last comment...

I haven't really worked with bootstrap, but maybe you could do something like this [pseudocode]:

```
def home
  if [x condition] 
    redirect_to index_seven_path
  else
    render :action => [y action]
  end
end
```

Comment: I changed it.  But, it's running the action `index` in the controller `home` instead of action `index7` in controller `workorders`

Comment: that's strange - is it reaching this request?  maybe it's getting redirected to home#index before it hits this?

Comment: It's displaying the `workorders/index7.html.erb` view.  I changed it from `_index7.html.erb` (a partial). But, it's not executing the index7 action in `workorders_controller.rb`.  Instead it's executing the `index` action in the `home_controller.rb`.

Comment: If I use this url `http://localhost:5000/workorders/index7` then it executes the `index7` action in the `workorders` controller. But, I want it to show on the home page not on a separate page.

Comment: could you make `http://localhost:5000/workorders/index7` a named route and call it (say `redirect_to index_seven_path`) where you need it?  Is the index7 action **always** what will be called, or it's conditional on something?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap and I'm rendering page `index7` in a tab and another page `index8` in a 2nd tab.